# Returns only starting price and ending price

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a `no` column, `name` column, `price` column and `date` column.

I need to find the max and min prices of the product according to date like `min date price` and `max date price` of that product.

I have tried many DAX function the output is as expected
sample data

[image].

Essentially I need to show the price of that product at the starting and end

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Mind to share what you've tried and what's not working?

Comment: Please share a dummy table of your data. And the output you want to achieve.